# C++ equivalent to the Python len() function?

Tags: c++

I have an integer and need to find out how many digits are in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little tricky to handle negative numbers and the case where the input is zero:

```
int length(int n)
{
   int len = 0;
   if (n < 0) { len = 1; n = -n; }
   while (n > 9) {
        n /= 10;
        len++;
   }
   return len+1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a careful, fast approach.  The spec was to count digits, so len needn't be set separately for negative values.  Can init len to 1 and return len.

Answer (score 10):

For positive numbers, use [log10](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log10/):

```
int a = 1234;
int len = static_cast<int>(log10(a)+1.);
```

If you need to be thorough:

```
int length(int a)
{
  int b = abs(a);
  if (b == 0) return 1;
  return static_cast<int>(log10(b)+1.);
}
```

With that said, it would be a better choice to do repeated division by 10 in practice.

```
int length(int a)
{
  int b = 0;
  for (a = abs(a); a != 0; b++, a /= 10) continue;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Begs the question, does the Standard allow an implementation where say `log10(10)` returns 0.9999999999...?  I just don't know (or trust implementations to comply as they'll do whatever their hardware does), so I prefer the digit-by-digit int approaches even though this is more mathematically elegant.  Thoughts?

Comment: This underestimates by 1 - ie. for your 1234 example, it returns 3. Also, it doesn't compile (under VC++ at least) because the call to log10 is ambiguous - you need to explicitly cast the int to a double first. And I guess you meant to pass b into log10 instead of a?

Comment: You're off by one.  log10(5) is 0.6989700... when you cast that back to an int, you get 0.  `5` certainly has more than zero digits.  Also, you take the abs(a) and put it in b, but then go ahead and take the log10 of (possibly non-positive) a anyway

Comment: I'd have to agree with you on that. Not only are they more assuredly correct, but they may be faster, too. My idea was to answer "a single standard c++ function" that would do what he wants... and this kinda fit the bill.

Comment: Josh, You really need to apply a ceiling function since the integer conversion truncates -- I've taken the liberty of editing your otherwise very good answer.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the correction, but shouldn't it be +1 as it is now?

Comment: @Tony: 1.0 is exactly representable as a double so I think you have a pretty good chance of it getting it right, but I don't know if it's guaranteed. Being floating point, quite possibly not. (Also: s/Begs/Raises/ ;-)

Comment: @Mark: My thought was that I would want 1.995 (that is log10(99)) to truncate to 1. (Then add one, which I missed.) So, your suggestion of ceiling would be spot on. Thank you for catching my error.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, 1.0 is representable, but might not the floating point log10 calculation itself sum successive values from lookup tables or sub-calculations as they home in on the answer? Could this not produce an answer ever so slightly less than 1.0/2.0 etc? I can only test on Intel/AMD right now, which seem fine. And I have read about the history of begging questions, but can't get excited about it.  "Which" where it should be "that" really bugs me though. ;->

Comment: @Tony: It might well, I was just thinking that there's a fair chance of that not being a problem if the argument and answer are integer - at least it doesn't appear to break for me either. I agree that it's not guaranteed, but seems like it might be one of those things that always does work - I guess it would depend how critical this code is :)

Answer (score 7):

You probably mean you have a string containing numbers rather than an int in python:

```
>>> i = 123456789
>>> len(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
>>> len(str(i))
9
```

If this is also the case in c++ it's easy to find the length of a string using:

```
my_str_value.length()
```

or for a C string using `strlen`

Answer (score 6):

There is no such function available in the C++ library. However you can use [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) for simplicity.

Try this (Handles negative numbers as well).

```
   int a =-12345,x;
   x = std::abs(a)
   std::stringstream s;
   s << x;
   std::cout<<s.str().size();
```

Comment: Localisation and factoring are good: `x = a < 0 ? -a : a;`, but I'd ditch x and put that expression straight into the stream.  Very C++, but very heavyweight.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... Python:

```
>>> len(5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    len(5)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

not what you wanted?

well, lets suppose you have an actual integer.  the log base 10 will tell you what you want to know numerically, that is if `yournumber == pow(10, digits)`, then `log10(yournumber) == digits`!  unfortunately, if your number is not an exact power of 10, you will have a fraction part to deal with.  That's easy enough to deal with, though, with the `floor()` function, which just rounds down.  be wary of negative numbers, as logarithms are undefined in the real numbers for non-positive values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << floor(log10(5))+1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << floor(log10(30))+1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << floor(log10(2000))+1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << floor(log10(16000))+1 << std::endl;
}
```

we have to add 1 because 10 to the 1'st is still 10, so we're off by one.  Add one to the exponent and you have digits!

Comment: Excellent explanation. +1 How do you feel about the possible precision issues with floating point that were raised in my answer's comments?

Comment: @JoshD: well, `log10(x)` is undefined for non-positive x, but aside from that issue, this will always be correct.  Note that `log10(10.0)` is exactly 1.0.  the floor of that is 1, 1+1 is two.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep dividing it by 10 (assuming it is an integer). You do this because you remove a digit each time the loop iterates.

something along the lines of:

```
int number;
int digits;
while (number > 0) 
{
    digits++;
    number /= 10;
}
```

You'll probably want to make sure the number is not zero to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

```
int intlen(float num) {
    int cnt = 0; 
    while(num >= 1) { 
        num = num / 10; 
        cnt++; 
    } 
    return cnt; 
}
```

Comment: The number 0 has 0 digits in it?

Comment: Negative numbers have no digits either?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example:

```
int numberDigits(int n) {
  char buffer[100];
  itoa(n,buffer,10);
  int len=0;
  while (buffer[len]!=0) { len++; }
  return len;
}
```

Comment: Worth listing as an alternative.  Should skip any leading '-'.  Despite avoiding strlen(), just the atoi() is sure to be slower than other div-by-10 solutions....

Comment: That would be an issue if speed is very sensitive in his application.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for the moment that `len()` in python returns the number of items in a sequence and not the number of digits in an integer, here's a function to count the number of digits in an integer *without* dividing (so it should be much faster than the similar solutions which use division).

```
int number_of_digits(int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 1;

    if (value < 0)
    {
        value *= -1;
    }

    while (i < value)
    {
        count++;
        i *= 10;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For extra speed, you can even replace the multiplication by ten with some bit twiddling:

```
i = ((i << 2) + i) << 1;
```

(The bit shifting is cool, but the multiplication may be "free" if your CPU can pipeline the multiplication on some otherwise unused multiplication unit - modern processors are a thing of beauty).